# Program that takes a set of letters from the user and prints out all of the combinations of valid words from a separate Dictionary file

Tags: python

I am having trouble with my current program that is supposed to take letters from user input, check them against a dictionary file that I already have, then return the possible words that can be made from the series of letters. Then, user input is supposed to dictate how many words are actually returned. I am new to python and am having trouble on how to check the letters against the dictionary file. I would really appreciate any and all help!

This is what I have so far:

```
def find_words (letters, dictionary):
    dictionary = open ('enable1.txt', 'r')
    r = dictionary.read()
    dictionary.close()
    dict = dictionary (word)
    w = 1
    for k in dict.keys():
        if k not in dictionary:
            w = 0
        if w == 1:
            print (word)

print (find_words (['e', 'u', 'c', 'i']))

def main ():
    letters = int (input ("please enter some letters... at least 1, but no more than 7\n>"))
    if letters < 1 and letters > 7:
        print (letters)
    try:    
       num_words = int (input ("What is the maximum number of words to display?\n>"))
  except ValueError:
       print ()
```

The desired output should look something like this:

```
Please enter some letters... at least 1, but no more than 7
> 123
Please enter some letters... at least 1, but no more than 7
>
Please enter some letters... at least 1, but no more than 7
> abcdefghijklmnop
Please enter some letters... at least 1, but no more than 7
> tdri

What is the maximum number of words to display?
> 1
Showing max 1 results:
dirt
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: I guess the issue is that I am not getting any input so I'm unsure if the program is working or not.

Comment: I take that to mean you're not getting an error stack trace as well?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of a function to find the anagrams of the characters entered. You can put a counter in and use `break` to exit the loop when you want. I trust the user input is working alright

```
dictionary_file = '/usr/share/dict/american-english' # Ubuntu's dictionary file

def anagrams(chars, dictionary_file):

    with open(dictionary_file) as f:

        # iterate through the dictionary file one line at a time
        for line in f:

            # Check to see that all characters are in there and the length matches
            if all(c in line for c in chars) and (len(line.strip()) == len(chars)):

                # Present the match
                print(line.strip())


anagrams('ritd', dictionary_file)
# dirt
```

if you want to capture the results and then process them some other way, you can change `print()` to `yield` and iterate over the generator. (this is like iterating over `range(42)`.

```
def anagrams(chars, dictionary_file):

    with open(dictionary_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if all(c in line for c in chars) and (len(line.strip()) == len(chars)):
                yield line.strip()


for match in anagrams('ritd', dictionary_file):
    print(match)
# dirt
```